# Struct Issue in C, using same Struct Multiple Source Files

Tags: c, arrays, struct, interface

I have a 'struct' which I would like to use in multiple sources files. I have declared the struct in the Header File and then have included in the sources files. It would be great if someone can assist me in this problem.
I am posting Header, Source and Error

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

struct dataBase
{
    char modelName;
    float capacity;
    int mileage;
    char color;
};

extern struct dataBase Inputs;

#endif  /* DATABASE_H */
```

---

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dataBase.h"


struct dataBase Inputs = NULL;

//size_t    Inputs_Size = 0;

int main (void)
```

---

```
#include "hw4_asharma_display.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dataBase.h"


void printLow(int size)
{
    // Declaring Variables
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %f %d %s\n", 
                Inputs[i].modelName, 
                Inputs[i].capacity, 
                Inputs[i].mileage, 
                Inputs[i].color);
    }
```

---

```
hw4_asharma_display.c:14:23: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                Inputs[i].modelName, 
                ~~~~~~^~
hw4_asharma_display.c:29:23: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
                Inputs[i].modelName,
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with having multiple files, and everything to do with the fact you're trying to use [] on a struct.

Comment: Your variable `Inputs` is not an array, you can't access the *i*-th item...

Comment: So what would be the best to access my Struct? and How can I fix the problem?

Comment: if you have just one `struct database Input`, then `Input.mileage` will access the corresponding attribute. If you want an array you should declare `struct database Inputs[NB]` and the be able to use `Inputs[i].mileage` for any i>=0 and i<NB.

Comment: you have to make `Inputs` an array. `extern struct dataBase Inputs[];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inputs` is not an array, so you can't just use the `[i]` index notation. You'll have to change its declaration from:

```
struct dataBase Inputs = NULL;
```

(btw the `NULL` part is pointless) to

```
struct dataBase Inputs[N];
```

Instead, if you meant to have only one element, keep the declaration:

```
struct dataBase Inputs;
```

but remove the `[i]` part:

```
    printf("%c %f %d %c\n", 
            Inputs.modelName, 
            Inputs.capacity, 
            Inputs.mileage, 
            Inputs.color);
```

Also, you will have to fill each element before printing or you will get all zeroes and blanks.

Comment: And the `extern` qualifier should also be in the cpp file instead of the header, no?

Comment: No that's right: the `extern` qualifier is used to declare `Inputs` as a global variable defined in some other compilation unit (in this case, in `main.c`). This way, any file including that header can use the global variable.